# Why do lambdas in c# seem to handle boolean return values differently?

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider this snippet of code:

```
Func<int, bool> TestGreaterThanOne = delegate(int a) {
                 if (a > 1) return (true);
                 else return(false);
                 };
```

In the above code, I cannot delete the "else return(false)" statement - the compiler warns that not all code paths return a value. But in the following code, which uses a lambda...

```
Func<int, bool> TestGreaterThanOne = a => a > 1;
```

I do not have to have an "else" statement - there are no compiler warnings and the logic works as expected.

What mechanism is at play here to make me not have an "else" statement in my lambda?

Comment: Just to clarify, the lambda expression doesn't have any special handling of bool specifically. You can write the `delegate` version in the same manner as Raymond Chen does below. The only lambda speciality here is the lack of specifying `return` for an in-line statement where the return value can be inferred (as it does in your example).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because in your lambda shorthand, there is no if statement either. Your lambda shorthand is equivalent to

```
Func<int, bool> TestGreaterThanOne = delegate(int a) { 
             return (a > 1);
             };
```

Therefore all code paths return a value.

Answer (score 2):

To add slightly to the other responses, in your lambda statement, `a > 1` evaluates to a boolean, which is then returned.

Generally, writing `return true;` and `return false;` statements is considered redundant. It's simpler to just return whatever the expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to rewriting the delegate, you're lambda abstraction is equivalent to

```
Func<int, bool> TestGreaterThanOne = a => {
             if (a > 1) return (true);
             else return(false);
             };
```

Where you can't delete the else branch either. Because it wouldn't return either. The current version works because `a > 1` is a boolean value (which is always present).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are handling boolean values differently in the case you mention.  The code is just doing two different things.  Since you define the `Func` as `Func<int, bool>` it requires a boolean return value.  The second piece of code always returns a boolean.  However the first piece of code does not return a boolean unless you include the else.

Answer (score 0):

`a>1` itself is a boolean, and that's why your lambda works.    you can almost think of an if statement as a function that takes a boolean parameter, so, you can do something like

```
boolean b = true

if(b)
    doSomething();
```

and it will compile, and execute doSomething